# How to insert an if in a switch case in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, action, confirm

I have this simple javascript function:

```
function updateDeleteUser(action, userid) {

    frm = document.getElementById("frmsearch");
    frm.frmUserId.value = userid;

    switch (action) {
    case 0:
        frm.action = "UpdateUser.jsp";
        break;
    case 1:
        confirm("Delete account?");
        if (confirm != false){
            frm.action = "DeleteUser.jsp";
        }
    }

    frm.submit();
}
```

Even if I click on 'NO' the function runs anyway and user gets deleted. What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything with the return value of the `confirm(…)` call, instead you use the `confirm` function itself as the compare value in your if-condition. You want

```
if (confirm("Delete account?")) {
    frm.action = "DeleteUser.jsp";
}
```

Notice that this has nothing to do with the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Confirm Method is wrong position as it always behaves like native function.#
Correct usage is as follows

```
case 1:
       // confirm("Delete account?");
        if (confirm("Delete account?") != false){
           frm.action = "DeleteUser.jsp";

        }
```